# A SharePoint list that includes "External" colums and SP Native columns

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to create a SharePoint list that includes columns from a SQL table (actually, two SQL tables) and columns that are native to SharePoint. Only the SharePoint native columns would need "CRUD" ability. The columns from the SQL Tables would be "read only".

For example, the list would contain:

From SQL Table "Orders": OrderID (PKEY), CustomerID (FKEY), OrderNumber, Qty and Total (all just "read only")

From SQL Table "Customers": CustomerName, CustomerAddress (linked to Orders table with "CustomerID" field). (all just "read only")

Local/Native SP Columns: OrderNotes, CustomerFeedback, DateReturned, DateDelivered (editable by the user)

I seem to have MANY possibilities, from creating my own Assembly that exposes both Tables to definining two or three content types in SP Designer, etc. Generally, we do all of our development in Visual Studio and stay away from SharePoint Designer. Although, I am not opposed to using it in the Prototype stage (it is quicker and I can always create an equivalent VS Assembly and solution that is deploy on the back end...). So, if you have any examples using SPD or VS, please feel free to provide either.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I think only way to do that is create a regular list and have new columns added to this list which are of type "external field"